# Swift enums property creation

Tags: swift

Are enum properties loaded/computed at creation time? If you have an enum defined as such:

```
enum Dwarf : Int {
    case Sleepy, Grumpy, Happy, Doc, ..
}

extension Dwarf: Printable {
    var description: String {
        println("description called")
        let names = ["Sleepy", "Grumpy", "Happy", "Doc", ...]
        return names[self.rawValue]
    }
}
```

Is 'description' created at the same time enum is defined or is it loaded only at run time upon use?

```
Dwarf.Happy // Enum instantiated - does description exist at this point in time?
println(Dwarf.Happy.description) // property is invoked - is this when description comes into existence?
```

Comment: You seem to have built yourself a test case right here in your question. When do you see it print "description called"? That's your answer.

Comment: Well I also expected it to be invoked when I did: println(Dwarf.Sleepy) but that just showed Enum in the playground, not the description so I wasn't sure whether that's just an aspect of Playgrounds or if it's something I don't yet understand about the language.

Comment: This doesn't compile for me.  Your `enum` won't have a `rawValue`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written, your code wouldn't even compile.  I don't know what the playground is showing you--I only know the Playground is far from the best place to test this sort of thing out.

[image]

This is what happens when your code is pasted into a non-Playground.

What you actually probably want is something more like this:

```
enum Dwarf: String {
    case Sleepy = "Sleepy"
    case Grumpy = "Grumpy"
    case Happy = "Happy"
    case Doc = "Doc"
}

extension Dwarf: Printable {
    var description: String {
        return self.rawValue
    }
}
```

In terms of whether Swift then carries the raw value with each, I don't know, and I'm not sure.

If we use `sizeOf` on a Swift `enum`, it tends to give us a value of 1... but there is probably optimization.  I imagine if we created an enum with over 256 values, `sizeOf` may give us `2`.

But if we call `sizeofValue` on the `rawValue` property of one of the `enum` values, it gives us different numbers (24 for strings), and this of course makes sense.

```
sizeOf(Dwarf)                       // gives 1
sizeofValue(Dwarf.Sleepy)           // also gives 1
sizeofValue(Dwarf.Sleepy.rawValue)  // gives 24
```

I imagine that when your `enums` are passed around, they've been optimized in terms of size, so an enum with less than 256 values has a size of 1 byte.  An `enum` with less than 65536 values has a size of 2 bytes, and an `enum` with any more values probably isn't particularly useful.

Meanwhile, calling `rawValue` probably does some Swift-magic, so the actual backing raw string only exists once you've requested it.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer about the Playground not being ideal. I am switching to the command-line REPL and I noticed that it gave me an error about how description should be declared public to match the Printable protocol's requirement.

Comment: I left out the enum being of type 'Int' which is why the error about rawValue in the extension showed up. Question updated to clarify.

Comment: @WillamHill I updated my answer.  I'm leaving the original part in there, but read the bottom half.  I don't think the backing type makes a difference in terms of optimizing memory footprint of your `enum`, and having String backing as I provided in my example makes a lot of other things simpler.